# How to localize a Sharepoint 2010? (content and interface)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How to localize a Sharepoint 2010? There ara some problems with content localization, because  different localized pages use same lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For localization of SharePoint interface, recommended approach would be to use Language Packs, that you install on top of your SharePoint server:

- [SharePoint Server language packs](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3411)
- [the deployment procedure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262108.aspx)

Take note, you need to install [SharePoint Foundation Language Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4731) in desired language before you install Language Pack for SharePoint Server.

For content localization, approach depends on the nature of your site and site template you are using. For example, if you are creating SharePoint Publishing Sites, there is an concept known as "Variations" that you can leverage for achieving localization of sites. For other templates, like Team Sites, you need to be creative, and perhaps create columns in your list that could contain appropriate content in each of your desired language.

This might also be of help: [Localizing SharePoint Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee696750.aspx)

I hope this answers your question?